Switch en Java + if/else
Estoy aprendiendo a programar con Java , ayer vi la función Switch/case y estoy haciendo algunas pruebas.
Ayer intenté añadir un boolean a uno de los "case" y no me dejaba , creo que Switch solo funciona con enteros o con strings.
Por otro lado , ahora intento hacer un if para cuando no se cumpla ninguna de las condiciones en el switch , pero ponga el número que ponga , siempre me aparece por pantalla el "Tu número es mayor que 6", aunque no sea así.
Alguien me puede ayudar? No sé si el fallo es de alguna tabulación , o de que no puedo mezclar una cosa y otra.
Mil gracias.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class intentodealgo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in) // En cuanto escribas esto sale arriba el import
                ) {

            System.out.print("Introduzca un número entero: ");
            int n = entrada.nextInt();
            boolean condicion = n > 6;
            entrada.nextLine(); // se usa un nextLine para borrar el intro del buffer

            switch (n) {
                case 1, 2, 3 ->
                    System.out.println("El número introducido es 1 , 2 o 3.");
                case 4, 5, 6 ->
                    System.out.println("El número introducido es 4 , 5 o 6");
                default ->
                    System.out.println("Tú número es otro.");

            }

            if (condicion == true);
            {
                System.out.println("Tu número es mayor que 6.");
            }

            // Primero se hace un nextInt y luego un nextline para limpiar el buffer
        }

    }
}


Por favor, edita la pregunta y elimina la imagen: el código debe ponerse como texto. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. Ayuda mucho poder copiar y pegar código de la pregunta a la respuesta. A muchos nos da pereza la idea de tener que escribir manualmente TODO el código de la pregunta en la respuesta, por lo que tendemos a ignorar las preguntas que usan imágenes innecesariamente.

Tienes razón , perdona , es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta y no me acordaba. Ya está modificado, muchas gracias! @PabloLozano

Sobre el switch: funciona con cualquier tipo primitivo, con enums y con String. Eso incluye boolean, pero no tiene mucho sentido usarlo porque sólo hay dos opciones y un if es lo ideal para este caso.
Sobre el if: el punto y coma sobra.


const condicion = 1;

if (condicion==0) {
  console.log("A");
}

if (condicion==0); {
  console.log("B");
}



¿Qué está pasando? Que en Java (y en mi ejemplo con Javascript, que tiene una sintaxis muy similar) las llaves posteriores son opcionales si sólo hay una línea de código en el bloque. Es decir, las dos formas siguientes son equivalentes:
if (condicion) 
    algo();

if (condicion) {
    algo();
}

pero si quitamos la sentencia antes del punto y coma  sigue siendo código válido:
if (condición); algo();

es equivalente a
if (condición) { 
// no hacemos nada
}
algo();

Por tanto sólo tienes que escribirlo así:
if (condicion) { //sin ; y no necesitas el '== true'
    System.out.println("Tu número es mayor que 6.");
}


Infinitas gracias , así me queda más claro.
